# How do I get a touch drag interaction?

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I'm working on a vega-lite project where I'd like a selection to be made with a click, and updated by dragging the selection.  As a concrete example see [this adaptation](https://bl.ocks.org/cwickham/6f9d41c401e73dd7ba5c42ff14814ab5) of Jake Vanderplas’s Multi-Value Tooltip in Vega-Lite.  A selection can be made with a single click, and a click drag results in the selection moving.

As implemented in the example, I found merging a mousedown with a mousemove event gave me this desired interaction for mouse events:

```
"on": "mousedown, [mousedown, mouseup] > mousemove"
```

Now, I'd like this to work similarly on touch devices, so that a selection can be made with a touch, and is updated through a touch drag.  I tried a similar approach of merging a touchstart and touchmove event:

```
"on": "mousedown, [mousedown, mouseup] > mousemove, touchstart, [touchstart, touchend] > touchmove"
```

But this doesn't seem to work on either my iPhone or with touch simulation in Firefox Developer Tools.  In both cases, a touch makes a selection but dragging doesn't update the selection.

Any ideas on why this isn't working, or how to achieve the interaction I want?

Comment: We will hopefully support touch natively soon (https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4208). In the meantime, you can see how I support touch in https://github.com/uwdata/falcon.